# foreign key not persisted symfony2 after a clone

Tags: symfony, doctrine, foreign-keys

I'm using symfony + Doctrine and I'm stuck with a problem:
I cloned an existing object and I would like to change a FK on the clone. It should be like that:

```php
$dafCloned = clone $daf;
$dafState = $dafStateRepository->findOneBy(
        array(
            'name' => 'saved',
            'dafType' => 'invoice',
            'company' => $daf->getSeller(),
        ));
$dafCloned->setDafState($dafState);
var_dump($dafState->getId());
var_dump($dafCloned->getDafState()->getId());
$this->em->persist($dafCloned);
$this->em->flush();
```

As you may have noticed, I got 2 var_dump here. Here are the print of the Custom Command calling this code :

```
int(5500)
int(5499)
```

5500 is the id I should have in db for $dafCloned, 5499 is the id I have for $daf.
I'd like to know WHY I got different id...My dafState should be the same. I'm probably missing something really stupid but I'm stuck on it since 9am...I even tried to delete all caches we have, moving `flush()` and `persist()` but cant help :s

EDIT : added the setDafState() method if needed, but this is basic :

```
public function setDafState(DafState $dafState) {

    $this->dafState = $dafState;

    return $this;
}
```

EDIT2 :
Here getDafState() :

```
/**
 * Get dafState
 *
 * @return MyPath\Entity\DafState
 */
public function getDafState() {
    return $this->dafState;
}
```

If you need more code sample, just ask for it, I'll  edit ;)

For the object, both are huge (Doctrine Object) and i can't find any way to get what could be useful :s. I cant grep dafState on $daf Object, output is still huge.

EDIT 3 :

```
if ($daf->getId() == 8902) // daf test which should be duplicated
                var_dump($dafCloned->getDafState() === $dafState);
```

output

```
bool(true)
```

Comment: Can you try to `var_dump` the full `DafState` object in both cases? Can you add `getDafState()` definition?

Comment: Edited question to add definition. Object cant be added, like explained in question.

Comment: and if you do `var_dump($dafCloned->getDafState() === $dafState)` you get `true` or `false`?

Comment: False... added to question. And thanks for suggestions

Comment: Oups wait, i placed the var_dump in the wrong line. Output is TRUE. Well, i'm gonna check the persistListener, maybe.

Comment: That makes more sense! :)

Comment: To get a nice debug output with doctrine use \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump() instead of var_dump(). Maybe Xdebug can help as well.

Comment: Yup, totally. I was like "this cannot be the REAL setter i have here..."

Comment: Here we go.

Thanks to @cheesemacfly i find out i have a prepersistListener which was resetting my dafState ! cant answer my own question for now !

So, next time you have something weird looking like the above problem, check your listener !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go.

Thanks to @cheesemacfly i find out i have a prePersistListener which was resetting my dafState !

So, next time you have something weird looking like the above problem, check your listener !

Answer (score 0):

```
$dafCloned = clone $daf; // Here your clone is the same object as the old one
$dafState = $dafStateRepository->findOneBy( // Here you get some fresh object
                array(
                        'name' => 'saved',
                        'dafType' => 'invoice',
                        'company' => $daf->getSeller(),
                ));
$dafCloned->setDafState($dafState); // Because this object is still managed by the entity manager it will set the $dafState on the old object (tracked by Id most likely)
var_dump($dafState->getId()); // Show the Id on the fresh object
var_dump($dafCloned->getDafState()->getId()); // Show the Id on the old object
$this->em->persist($dafCloned); // overwrite the old object
$this->em->flush();
```

This Post will be helpful to you: [How to re-save the entity as another row in Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071094/how-to-re-save-the-entity-as-another-row-in-doctrine-2)
I will update my answer if this doesn't solve your issue

Comment: Well if i'm not wrong in this case
    
    var_dump($daf->getDafState()->getId());

would give me the same than

    var_dump($dafState->getId());

?