# Cloning object after getting data from a form in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic here.

I have a form, and when the user updates the fields of the form I don't want to update the underlying entity but want to create a new entity with the new values.

To clone Doctrine entities I followed the indication [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071094/how-to-re-save-the-entity-as-another-row-in-doctrine-2).

So my code is (let's say I want to clone the object with id=3:

```
    $id = 3;
    $storedBI = $this->getDoctrine()
                     ->getRepository('AppBundle:BenefitItem')
                     ->find($id);
    $form = $this->createForm(new BenefitItemFormType(), $storedBI);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();  
            $newBI = clone $form->getData();
            $em->persist($newBI);
            $em->flush();
        }
```

It simply does not work. It properly creates a new object with the new data passed from the form (which is ok), but also updates the "old" stored object with the same new data.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to clone your object during the form creation:

`$form = $this->createForm(new BenefitItemFormType(), clone $storedBI);`

If this does not work, try to `detach` your cloned object first.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin Paap, some complication arose (you can have a look at a detailed explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29347310/symfony2-cloning-entities-with-collections-and-entity-field-type ). Maybe you can help. Thank you immensely!