# Does Doctrine's sugested __clone logic ever actually run?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, clone

On Doctrine's [documentation page](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/implementing-wakeup-or-clone.html) that describes how to implement __clone, the following logic is used:

```
<?php
class MyEntity
{
    private $id; // This is the identifier of the entity.
    //...

    public function __clone()
    {
        // If the entity has an identity, proceed as normal.
        if ($this->id) {
            // ... Your code here as normal ...
        }
        // otherwise do nothing, do NOT throw an exception!
    }

    //...
}
```

... and the following explanation is given (bold added by me):

> These implementations are possible and safe because **when Doctrine
>   invokes these methods, the entities never have an identity (yet).**
>   Furthermore, it is possibly a good idea to check for the identity in
>   your code anyway, since it's rarely the case that you want to
>   unserialize or clone an entity with no identity.

Doesn't this mean that the branch titled `Your code here as normal` will absolutely never be reached and is therefor useless? What am I missing here?

Comment: The documentation has no example and is poor.

Comment: Although you are not asking for related entities like in the duplicate, the accepted answer shows an example on how to implement correctly `clone`

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071094/how-to-re-save-the-entity-as-another-row-in-doctrine-2) is related too